# Why is the div I'm scraping coming back as empty

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm practicing some web scraping using node and cheerio on the William Hill website, but when I get to a certain point in the code, it almost stops and despite the div being full of html and inspect element showing this, and when calling .html() it just returns , as if it's empty. Any targeting of elements within this div return null.

```
request('https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/football/competitions/OB_TY295/English-Premier-League/matches/OB_MGMB/Match-Betting', (error, response, html) => {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)

        const bet = $('#football div[data-test-id="events-group"]')

        console.log(bet.html())
        
    }
})
```

I'm completely new to web scraping so I hope this makes sense, and please if possible try to 'dumb down' your answers as much as possible.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are many protections against screen scraping that webmasters deploy to prevent this from happening. A few are, limiting requests from IP addresses, looking for specific information in the headers (like browser type) and some of them even certain types of cookies.

As AbdulSohu pointed out, curl returns nothing (neither would a direct request or even JavaScript fetch) because the request lacks what the web server needs to give you the html. It's also very brittle because websites could change their html code.

Selenium is an option, but if you want to dig into it, start investigating the minimum you'd need to return something from that site using request by adding appropriate headers to fool the web server into thinking you're a browser.

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following to really see if I could get something following the specific link you posted:

```
curl "https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/football/competitions/OB_TY295/English-Premier-League/matches/OB_MGMB/Match-Betting"
```

If you don't know what `curl` is, you can learn about it a bit more [here](https://www.keycdn.com/support/popular-curl-examples#what-is-curl). The command is supposed to return the html content for this specific page to me, in my terminal. What did I get?

`<html></html>`

So, basically, nothing.

In general, when you try to target specific containers and `div`s on an html page specified by a very specific hyperlink, you can run into many issues. For instance, the website administrators could change what the `div`s are called, the hyperlinks could redirect elsewhere etc.

What is less likely to happen, though, is that they change the structure of the website. It is still likely to happen, just less likely. So, in this case, it would probably be really beneficial if you could just write a [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/) program to browse and scrape the page like a human would with inspect element. For instance, I found [this](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/introduction-to-web-scraping-using-selenium-7ec377a8cf72) beginner tutorial.

Comment: I'm trying to load the page using selenium, but it just loads the browser to 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,', rather than the page I specified. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?                                                                                                                    const { Builder, By, Key, util } = require('selenium-webdriver')
const example = async () => {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
    await driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
}

example()